# Detect card type (RFID, NFC, Magnetic, ...)

Tags: rfid, nfc, magnetic-stripe-card

I would like to know how the communication between my gym card and the checking point works.

I bought an ACR122U reader, but it seems that I can't read my card with it, the card is not recognized as something readable with that adapter.
The card hasn't the black stripe that suggests that it is a magnetic one.
When I do the check-in in the gym I just lay the card over the checking point for 1 second.

How do I know which type of card it is? Which usb device should I buy in order to see how the communication works and make some read/write operation over the card?

Comment: I'd look at the gym's reader, instead. Or ask the gym what program they use to program the cards. That will tell you.

Comment: @schroeder Usually people who you don't have so much confidence with, are not happy to answer this kind of questions :S. I wish I could figure out by myself what technlogy are they using.

Comment: I don't agree at all. And it does depend on how you ask. "Hey, I was looking at using something like these cards for a project I'm working on. What's the software called that you use to program these?" works a lot better than "I demand to know what card model and type you use!!!1!1!!"

Comment: That's called social engineering :)